# Inserting one array into 2 tables based off of array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array, and it has 10+ indexes.

What I want to do is set variable $table based on the index's, so that it will insert

```
Array[0] - Array[9] to $table = table1
```

and it would insert

```
Array[10] - Array[14] to $table = table2
```

I don't want to use an if statement because I need them both inserted

I was hoping to keep  this all in one query and use $table (if it's possible)

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$table = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value)
  if ($key <= 9)
    $table['table1'][$key] = $value;
  else
    $table['table2'][$key] = $value;
```

This will keep it all as one array.  Which I think is kinda what you were going for.

I'm terrible at SQL query so the bellow is just pseudo for if each key is a column in the table:

```
foreach($table as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'table1'){
        foreach($value as $key => $value){
            //INSERT INTO table1 ($key) VALUES ($value) 
        {
    if($key == 'table2'){
        foreach($value as $key => $value){
            //INSERT INTO table2 ($key) VALUES ($value) 
        {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What would I replace my `$table` with in my query? `$table[]` or something?

Comment: Depends how how your table is setup.  Is each key going to have it's own row? Or are key's 0-9 a column in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

So you create 2 arrays and work with them:

```
$table1 = array() ;  //Save data into arrays so you can put it in a database (?)
$table2 = array() ;

foreach(array_values($array) as $key => $value){
  if ($key <= 9)
    $table1[] = $value ;
  else
    $table2[] = $value ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically is splitting an array into sub arrays, right? If so, then look at `array_chunk()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php